Can upvotes on Stackoverflow be modelled using a Random Walk?
I have a (very controversial) theory on how people submit votes on stackoverflow questions.
Suppose a question is posted at time $t=0$ :

Condition 1: If the score on the question is rapidly increasing, the future score is also more likely to increase
Condition 2: If the score on the question is rapidly decreasing, the future score is more more likely to decrease
Condition 3: In the long run, the score on this question is likely to stabilize

I was wondering if this voting behavior can be characterized using a modified version of a random walk such the above 3 conditions are obeyed.  Here is my attempt to do this.
Part 1: Definitions
First, I defined the state space and the main equations of the stochastic process (this took a lot of trial and error):
$$X_t \in \{-1, 0, 1\} \quad \text{for } t = 1, 2, 3, ...$$
$$\text{Let } S_t = \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_{t-i} $$
$$p_{1,t} = P(X_t = -1) = \frac{e^{a_1(t) - b S_t}}{Z_t}$$
$$p_{2,t} = P(X_t = 0) = \frac{e^{a_2(t)}}{Z_t}$$
$$p_{3,t} = P(X_t = 1) = \frac{e^{a_3(t) + b S_t}}{Z_t}$$
Normalization factor:
$$\text{where } Z_t = e^{a_1(t) - b S_t} + e^{a_2(t)} + e^{a_3(t) + b S_t}$$
$$a_i(t) = c_i - d_i \log(t+1) \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, 3$$
Model parameters:
$$b, c_i, d_i > 0 $$
Part 2 - Proving Condition 3:
To prove condition 3, I thought that I could evaluate the limit probabilities of each score as time becomes bigger. This should show that the probabilities of +1 and -1 become 0 and the probability of 0 becomes 1.
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{1,t} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_1(t) - b S_t}}{Z_t} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{c_1 - d_1 \log(t+1) - b S_t}}{e^{c_1 - d_1 \log(t+1) - b S_t} + e^{c_2 - d_2 \log(t+1)} + e^{c_3 - d_3 \log(t+1) + b S_t}} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t}}{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t} + e^{c_2} (t+1)^{-d_2} + e^{c_3} (t+1)^{-d_3} e^{b S_t}} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t}}{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t} + e^{c_2} (t+1)^{-d_2} + e^{c_3} (t+1)^{-d_3} e^{b S_t}} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{c_2-c_1} (t+1)^{d_1-d_2} e^{b S_t} + e^{c_3-c_1} (t+1)^{d_1-d_3} e^{2b S_t}}
\end{align*}
$$
Depending on what constraints we chose for $d_1, d_2, d_3$ -  we can see tha that the limit becomes 0:
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{1,t} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } d_1 > d_2 \text{ or } d_1 > d_3 \\
\frac{1}{1 + e^{c_2-c_1} + e^{c_3-c_1}} & \text{if } d_1 = d_2 = d_3 \\
\frac{1}{1 + e^{c_2-c_1}} & \text{if } d_1 = d_2 < d_3 \\
\frac{1}{1 + e^{c_3-c_1}} & \text{if } d_1 = d_3 < d_2 \\
1 & \text{if } d_1 < d_2 \text{ and } d_1 < d_3
\end{cases}
$$
We can repeat the same analysis for the other probabilities:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{3,t} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_3(t) + b S_t}}{Z_t} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{c_3} (t+1)^{-d_3} e^{b S_t}}{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t} + e^{c_2} (t+1)^{-d_2} + e^{c_3} (t+1)^{-d_3} e^{b S_t}} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_3} (t+1)^{d_3-d_1} e^{-2b S_t} + e^{c_2-c_3} (t+1)^{d_3-d_2} e^{-b S_t} + 1}
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{3,t} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } d_3 > d_1 \text{ or } d_3 > d_2 \\
\frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_3} + e^{c_2-c_3} + 1} & \text{if } d_1 = d_2 = d_3 \\
\frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_3} + 1} & \text{if } d_3 = d_1 < d_2 \\
\frac{1}{e^{c_2-c_3} + 1} & \text{if } d_3 = d_2 < d_1 \\
1 & \text{if } d_3 < d_1 \text{ and } d_3 < d_2
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{2,t} &= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{a_2(t)}}{Z_t} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{e^{c_2} (t+1)^{-d_2}}{e^{c_1} (t+1)^{-d_1} e^{-b S_t} + e^{c_2} (t+1)^{-d_2} + e^{c_3} (t+1)^{-d_3} e^{b S_t}} \\[10pt]
&= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_2} (t+1)^{d_2-d_1} e^{-b S_t} + 1 + e^{c_3-c_2} (t+1)^{d_2-d_3} e^{b S_t}}
\end{align*}
$$
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} p_{2,t} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } d_2 > d_1 \text{ or } d_2 > d_3 \\
\frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_2} + 1 + e^{c_3-c_2}} & \text{if } d_1 = d_2 = d_3 \\
\frac{1}{e^{c_1-c_2} + 1} & \text{if } d_2 = d_1 < d_3 \\
\frac{1}{1 + e^{c_3-c_2}} & \text{if } d_2 = d_3 < d_1 \\
1 & \text{if } d_2 < d_1 \text{ and } d_2 < d_3
\end{cases}
$$
Part 3: Proving Condition 1 and Condition 2
My interpretation of these conditions are that "bursts" of +1 are more likely to be followed by other bursts of +1, and the same for bursts of -1. To show this, we need to compare the probabilities of +1 and -1 given different recent histories.

Scenario 1: Many recent +1s (large positive $S_t$)

$$
\begin{align*}
p_{3,t} &= \frac{e^{a_3(t) + b S_t}}{Z_t} \\[10pt]
p_{1,t} &= \frac{e^{a_1(t) - b S_t}}{Z_t}
\end{align*}
$$
The ratio of these probabilities is:
$$
\frac{p_{3,t}}{p_{1,t}} = \frac{e^{a_3(t) + b S_t}}{e^{a_1(t) - b S_t}} = e^{a_3(t) - a_1(t) + 2b S_t}
$$
As $S_t$ increases, this ratio grows exponentially, making +1 much more likely than -1.

Scenario 2: Many recent -1s (large negative $S_t$)

Using the same ratio:
$$
\frac{p_{3,t}}{p_{1,t}} = e^{a_3(t) - a_1(t) + 2b S_t}
$$
As $S_t$ becomes more negative, this ratio decreases exponentially, making -1 much more likely than +1.
Conclusion: While I think the stochastic process that I defined somewhat characterizes the desired voting behavior, I am not sure if it does so completely. Can someone please help me understand if my mathematical analysis truly validates whether or not this stochastic process obeys these conditions?
Thanks!

You can query actual SE voting data. Consider checking whether the model matches that data before spending time proving things about it. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/the-erdos-graph-for-tex-se for an example built from data queries.

The question of how to model real-world processes is always at least somewhat subjective. "All models are wrong, but some are useful". It's worth noting that each vote is probably not independent of the previous votes, so random walk is probably not the best model. Many people attest that they cast votes based on what score they think the question "ought" to have, so they'll be less likely to upvote if the score is already very high.

In the modeling, you ignored key external factors that radically affect the voting process such as IT related ones (being listed as a hot or an interesting question), being targeted by some members who can close/delete or vote to close/delete a post (for low quality or other reasons), the size of the supporting network of the member who posted, positive, negative, or somehow challenging comments on the post, the competition among who answered or want to answer the post, etc.
